# Tensorflow: Using a value of a placeholder into another placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am using different sets of datasets in the same neural network, each one with a different number of outputs (9,12,15,21,65 each one) In order to do this, I tried to use an integer placeholder and use this parameter as parameter for another placeholder (in order to maintain modifiable size of the outputs) like this:

```
numb_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,numb_labels])
```

Once I do this, I receive a long exception telling me that I cannot put a tensor value where a should put a number or a string. Ok, To try to solve this then I made a condition based on the placeholder which I use

```
numb_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,shpeData]) 
if(numb_labels==9):
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,9]) #[batch_size]
elif(numb_labels==12):
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,12])
elif(numb_labels==15):
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,15])
elif(numb_labels==21):
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,21])
else:
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,65])
```

But then it creates a 65 placeholder and when I try to add the dataset of 9 possible labels, I receive an exception telling me I'm trying to insert an array of size 9 into a tensor of size 65

I kept making tricks into this and then I decided to play the whole thing so I try to use the conditions as depending on the numb_labels as I could like this

```
    if(numb_labels==9):
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,9]) #[batch_size]
    if(numb_labels==12):
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,12])
    if(numb_labels==15):
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,15])
    if(numb_labels==21):
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,21])
    if(numb_labels==65):
        y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,65])
```

... and also (this is an example of 5 cases which are same as this one)

```
if(numb_labels==65):
    W_fc3 = weight_variable([1024,65], 'fc3', 'trunc') #Modified here
    b_fc3 = bias_variable([65], 'fc3')   
    k = tf.constant(0.00000001, shape=[1]) #Constant value added to prevent underflow (probability of having zero terms)
    h_fc3 = tf.matmul(h_fc2_drop, W_fc3) + b_fc3
    y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(h_fc3) + k
    print(y_conv)
    with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
        cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_))
    with tf.name_scope('train'):
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

    with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y_conv,1),tf.arg_max(y_,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

    tf.scalar_summary('cost', cost)
    tf.scalar_summary('accuracy', accuracy)
```

However when I'm going to train, I receive an exception telling me that the train_step is not defined... my tricks are finished. Can someone please tell me how can I put a placeholder value in another placeholder without causing so much trouble?? Is that possible or should I keep each architecture separated as till now.

I also thought of using

```
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,None])
```

But with my output in the network I do need the fixed number of labels (or at least what TF says)

Is there a way of using a placeholder value as input for another placeholder or should I just keep 5 different scripts for 5 different datasets?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want to train a single neural net that takes a variable number of inputs, or do you simply want to write a script that trains a neural net with a fixed number of inputs where that number is determined at runtime?  If the latter, simply read the input size from, e.g., the command line at runtime.  If it's the former, you'll have to explain exactly what kind of architecture you have in mind.

Comment: I want to train a neural net with 5 different sets of data (in separated processes but using the same NN structure), the data is variable in training inputs and outputs (outputs are 10, 12, 15, 21, 45, inputs are 1000, 30000, 80000, 150000, 210000) I use batch data, so there wouldn't be any problem with training inputs but the size training outputs and test data is also variable, so that's why my question about how to use a placeholder in order to get from it the size that later would become into the output training data (or another option if it exists) .

Comment: You can't use a Tensor as part of a placeholder shape annotation. Shapes must be known at graph construction time. But in this case, why don't you just put None instead of a concrete size for the dimension? None means "unknown at graph construction time".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually already did it, but later I have to reshape the data in order to change from a CNN to a FCN, so I do need a dynamic parameter. I solved it in a primitive way... I put everything in a line (Not the best result) and calling a resetting graph method every time I change of dataset. Anyway I will look at your idea